# devtools::check() failing due to percent sign in table generated by code chunk in R function documentation

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, roxygen2

I am writing function documentation for an R package and I am including the following code chunk in said documentation:

````
#' Function title
#' 
#' Function description
#' 
#' @section My Section:
#' 
#' ```{r product-table}
#' x <- data.frame(PRODUCT = c("A", "B", "C"), PCT_OF_SALE = c("20%", "50%", "30%"))
#' knitr::kable(x)
#' ```
#' 
#' @md
#' @name custom-doc-name
````

The issue is that the percent sign is an escape character in the documentation generated by roxygen2. The result is that the closing table data tag `</td>` is escaped by the percent sign.

```latex
\if{html}{\out{<div class="sourceCode r">}}\preformatted{x <- data.frame(PRODUCT = c("A", "B", "C"),
                PCT_OF_SALE = c("20\%", "50\%", "30\%"))
knitr::kable(x)
}\if{html}{\out{</div>}}\if{html}{\out{
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> PRODUCT </th>
   <th style="text-align:left;"> PCT_OF_SALES </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> A </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> 20% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> B </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> 50% </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> C </td>
   <td style="text-align:left;"> 30% </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The documentation renders fine for html viewing in RStudio, but I get the following warning from `devtools::check()`

```
W  checking Rd files (343ms)
   custom-doc-name.Rd:23-114: Must contain verbatim text
   problem found in ‘custom-doc-name.Rd’
```

I assume this warning comes from when R tries to use latex to generate the PDF version of the manual, runs into the percent sign, and doesn't see the closing `</td>`. How can I escape the percent sign in the table so that in renders in HTML and also appeases `devtools::check()`?

Below are versions of the relevant packages:

```r
packageVersion("devtools")
#> [1] ‘2.4.5’
packageVersion("roxygen2")
#> [1] ‘7.2.3’
packageVersion("RMarkdown")
#> [1] ‘2.19’
packageVersion("knitr")
#> [1] ‘1.41’
```

from DESCRIPTION

```
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE, roclets = c("rd", "namespace", "collate"))
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
VignetteBuilder: knitr
```

Comment: It's not clear from what you posted what the .Rd file looks like.  Can you show us a fully reproducible example?

Comment: I tried to guess at your source, and didn't see the problem.  Percents were escaped (but the code was different; maybe different package versions?)

Comment: @user2554330 I should have included more info from my environment. Please look at the revised post for info on installed versions of packages as well as DESCRIPTION entries.

Comment: Your `Rmarkdown` and `knitr` are both old versions.  This looks like a bug in one of them; maybe it's been fixed now.